# How to pass authentication details to application inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I've a web page and want to show Jenkins' webpage in it hence used `iframe` like -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/view/Nightly%20Builds%20/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

But `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/view/Nightly%20Builds%20/` opens with login page and hence content could not be shown directly. Actually I want to show content of the page without login.

Is there any way we can pass authentication details/token to website inside frame?

Comment: You cannot manipulate the content of the Iframe but you can use the URL to pass some information.
You could create some kind of Token (like jwt.io) to tell the other application who you are, and that the User is logged in, but you will need to talk to the other side, who owns the embedded website as well

Answer (score 15):

I think you need to handle the page.

1. I assume you have javascript function for handling the username and password or authToken validation

   function authTokenValidate(token) {
        api for validating the token and then redirection to 
        http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/view/Nightly%20Builds%20/
   }

   or Assume you have http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/view/Nightly%20Builds%20/ page which validate the authToken and let you stay on the page or redirect you to login.
2. Pass the authToken in the url as query params in the Iframe http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/view/Nightly%20Builds%20/?auth=AUTH_TOKEN

3. So When page load http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/view/Nightly%20Builds%20/ get auth query 
   params from url and call the function that validates the auth token if valid then let 
   user stay on the page else redirect to the login page.

Comment: This doesn't sound secure because URL can be logged by different systems and you don't want to log the security token.